# 2 versions of libssl on one system

Tags: openssl, debian-jessie

I'm running Debian 8 on a VPS with KVM. I wanted to upgrade libssl to a newer version as required by some scripts, so I recompiled libssl from testing. I was hoping the new version would replace the old one, but the package names being different `dpkg -i` installed libssl1.0.2 alongside the existing libssl1.0.0, whereas openssl and libssl-dev got updated to 1.0.2. Applications I had installed before seem to be linked to libssl1.0.0, like:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/mysql
...
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fe34702a000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fe346c2f000)
```

But on the other hand:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
```

While nothing appears to be broken so far I'm just wondering if it is normal to have 2 versions of libssl on one system. Will it not give this system a headache to have e.g. mariadb use libssl1.0.0 and nginx libssl1.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research. Yes, it is possible to have multiple versions of core libraries, but they have to be controlled, linked, etc by hand. A no-go under normal circumstances and to be avoided if you have choice. Some opinions are to be found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/two-versions-of-libssl-in-the-system-4175562050/#post5467567) (in English) and [here](https://forum.dug.net.pl/viewtopic.php?pid=294572#p294572) (in Polish). Most people tend to agree that it is better to use Debian Testing rather than maintain core libraries by hand.